# select single entry from EF with multiple non primary key parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, select

I'm pretty new to C# and EF. I would like to know how I'll be able to select an entry from an EF model with multiple non primary key parameters.

I hadn't much success so far.

```
var context = new CommentEntities();

var comments = context.T_OPT_REP_COMMENT.Where(C => C.REP_ID == parameters[0] &
               C.CUSTOMER_ID == parameters[1] &
               C.CONTRACT_POS_ID == parameters[2] &
               C.PRODUCT_ID == parameters[3] &
               C.CATEGORY == parameters[5]).Select(C => C.COMMENT_TEXT);
```

The result of this select isn't really that what I want.

Comment: _"The result of this select isn't really that what I want."_ - despite the easy to spot mistake @ken2k already addresses, for future questions it would really help if you'd explain what you expect to see and what you do see. We cannot guess what you see and what you want to see.

Answer (score 3):

Use `&&` instead of the bitwise operator `&`.

Comment: how does this change implementation in the direction of the desired behavior?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: that would depend on which LINQ provider he's using

Comment: @JohnSaunders exactly, but OPs question doesn't rely on particular LINQ provider, as far as I understood vaguely stated question.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you.

```
var comments = context.T_OPT_REP_COMMENT.Where(C => C.REP_ID == parameters[0] &&
               C.CUSTOMER_ID == parameters[1] &&
               C.CONTRACT_POS_ID == parameters[2] &&
               C.PRODUCT_ID == parameters[3] &&
               C.CATEGORY == parameters[5]).Select(C => C.COMMENT_TEXT);
```

As you can notice you have had only `&` instead of `&&`. You can specify multiple `WHERE` clauses in lambda expressions using `&&`. Bitwise operator `&` is used in lambda expressions for capture clauses and not for boolean conditions.

Still, I wonder that you are comparing all the properties. Don't you have `CUSTOMER_ID` together with `PRODUCT_ID` unique? You could have done like this if you had so:

```
var comments = context.T_OPT_REP_COMMENT.Single(....)
```